# Python splitting text in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Splitting Text in a Column into Multiple Rows in a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':['34','22','19'],'Ticket':['23:44:55','66:77:88','43:68:05 56:34:12'],'PlusOne':['0','0','1'],})
```

Split out the two values in the third row

```
ticket_series = df['Ticket'].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
```

Get rid of the stack:
 Drop the level to line up with the DataFrame

```
ticket_series.index = ticket_series.index.droplevel(-1)
ticketdf = pd.DataFrame(ticket_series)
del df['Ticket']
df.join(ticketdf)
df
```

I don't understand why it can't join together!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, `DataFrame` constructor is not necessary, only need `name of Series` for column name:

```
ticket_series = df['Ticket'].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
ticket_series.index = ticket_series.index.droplevel(-1)
ticket_series.name = 'new'
```

Another solution for new `Series`:

```
ticket_series = (df['Ticket'].str.split(expand=True)
                             .stack()
                             .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                             .rename('new'))

print (ticket_series)
0    23:44:55
1    66:77:88
2    43:68:05
2    56:34:12
Name: new, dtype: object


print (df.drop('Ticket', 1).join(ticket_series).reset_index(drop=True))
  PlusOne age       new
0       0  34  23:44:55
1       0  22  66:77:88
2       1  19  43:68:05
3       1  19  56:34:12
```

Comment: What if I want to only split the 2 data: 3:68:05 and 56:34:12 into two rows?

Comment: Not sure if understand.Can you explain more?

Comment: I don't understand why my code can't join the two dataframe together